# "iCloud Download" column in iTunes keeps reappearing

Tags: itunes, icloud

I updated my iTunes on my computer, and one of the things I noticed was that the "iCloud Download" column had now appeared on top of my music library. Now, I don't use iCloud for my music, so I right-clicked the bar and turned it off.

A few minutes later, the iCloud Download tab was back again. I could've sworn I'd turned it off, but just to be sure I right-clicked and turned it off again.

A few more minutes pass, and the iCloud Download tab is right there back again. Every time I turn it off, it just keeps reappearing sooner or later. I have Automatic Downloads for music checked off, so I don't know what is causing this.

This is very annoying. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer that doesn't require you stay logged out of the iTunes store (found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/3h5ggj/disable_icloud_download_column_in_itunes_1222/), whose poster found it [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7173218)).

- In iTunes, press <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> or click `Menubar/View/Music`.
- Click the `Playlist` button from the center-top row of the the iTunes window, below the large Apple logo.
- Click `Menubar/View/Only Music Available Offline`.
- Repeat for all other media types: <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> or `Menubar/View/Movies`, <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> or `Menubar/View/TV Shows`, etc.
- Return to `Music Playlists`, and the `iCloud Download` column is gone, no matter whether you're signed into the Store, no matter whether you've enabled/disabled Apple brand subscription-based streaming, and even after quit/relaunch of iTunes.

Comment: Tell me about. Or better, tell Apple: http://apple.com/feedback

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you log out of the store after you've used it. Go to Store > Log Out and this should sort the problem.

Comment: I really don't want to be logging in and out all the time, but if that's the only solution, then I guess I don't mind.

Comment: I, for one, do mind.

Answer (score -1):

I just removed it. And you must deactivate it from music, movies and TV for it to remove it